# Numero que se encuentra después de ":" y antes de un "-" en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una cadena que no siempre tiene la misma longitud, pero lo que quiero hacer es que pueda obtener un numero que se encuentra despues de ":" y antes de un "-", esta es mi cadena

> Numero:9-JOSEPEREZ

He intentado obtnener el numero con SUBSTRING(CADENA, 8, 3) pero me obtiene también el guion

Comment: El tercer parámetro es el tamaño de tu subcadena, cámbialo a 1 para que te traiga sólo el número.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejo otra solución que consiste en primero tomar todo lo que está a la izquierda del guión (-) y de ahí tomar todo lo que queda a la derecha de los dos puntos (:). Incluye aparte una validación para no regresar valores inválidos.

```
DECLARE @Cadena varchar(1000) = 'Numero9764-JOSEPEREZ';

SELECT SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING( @Cadena, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @Cadena)), NULLIF(CHARINDEX( ':', @Cadena), 0) + 1, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de conseguirlo sin importar el tamaño de la cadena sería buscando el indice de cada uno de los elementos y jugar con sus dimensiones para sacar el valor que tienen en medio:

```
SUBSTRING(CADENA, CHARINDEX(CADENA, ':', 0) + 1, CHARINDEX(CADENA, '-', 0) - CHARINDEX(CADENA, ':', 0) - 1)
```

Comment: Tu línea no funciona en mi equipo, tal vez sea porque charindex se usa al revés: primero el caracter a buscar y luego la cadena, algo como esto: `select SUBSTRING(CADENA, CHARINDEX(':', CADENA, 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', CADENA, 0) - CHARINDEX(':', CADENA, 0) - 1)`

Comment: @solamente me envio un error  "Se pasó un parámetro de longitud no válido a la función LEFT o SUBSTRING."

Comment: Acaso la gente no prueba sus respuestas antes de publicar?

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras  gracias si funcionó, era lo que necesitaba

Comment: @solamente gracias casi estaba bien tu respuesta

Comment: @LuisCazares las pruebo si tengo el entorno montado :) pero una vez tienes la lógica solucionar los problemas de compilación es trivial